# Install of ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04 Failed

Tags: ros, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, groovy-beta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to undate ROS to Groovy from fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04. I have disabled Fuerte and then install Groovy following the manual on the Wiki step by step. When I installed the package:

sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full

E: Unable to locate package ros-groovy-desktop-full
Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this error?
(A beginner of Linux and ROS)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49630/install-of-ros-groovy-on-ubuntu-12.04-failed/) by [Rickardo Leos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3712/rickardo-leos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the install page: Desktop-Full Install: (Recommended) Not available in beta 1:

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same error messages because I forgot to run "sudo apt-get update" after setting up my keys.  As of 2013-01-19, ros-groovy-desktop-full is available in the repositories, and I have personally installed it.

---

Originally posted by [bd.at.rivenhill](https://answers.ros.org/users/1812/bd.at.rivenhill/) with karma: 46 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1